# search - componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

the search engine works when I type something into a nice search, but when it deletes the input content, unfortunately everything disappears and I would like all the results to be returned. Can you do that?

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.search.length === 0) return
    if (prevState.search !== this.state.search) {
      fetch(`http://api/Routes/Search?word=${this.state.search}`)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return response;
          }
          throw Error(response.status)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>
          this.setState({
            trasy: [...data]
          })
        )
        .catch(error => console.log(error))

    }

  }
```

Comment: Why not execute this code inside a onChange or onInput handler for the search input?

Comment: the boss told me to use it componentDidUpdate

Comment: you would have to handle it on the backend that if there is no search input, return all the results. you can't show what don't get from the backend on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove the first if statement it should work. Did you try doing this? If you initialise the search property with an empty string then this will trigger this when you remove all the search query.